# CreateService() call is successful, even though dependency doesn't exist

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service

I've the following code:

```
TCHAR buff[200];
_tcscpy_s(buff, argv[3]);  //CONSIDER argv[3] as XYZSvc
_tcscat(buff, L"\0\0");

schService = CreateService(
    schSCManager,
    lpszServiceName, 
    lpszDisplayName, 
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
    SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
    SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
    lpszBinaryPathName,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    buff, // INITIALIZED ABOVE
    NULL,
    NULL);
```

This call executes successfully, even though XYZSvc doesn't exist. Can someone tell what's wrong with this code?

Comment: For clarity we should see your error checking code. We have to assume you got it right. >90% of posters don't, so please forgive a bit scepticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the service fine, even if the dependencies you specify are not valid. Any failure would occur when the SCM attempts to start the service and resolve the dependencies.